# How can I programatically add shipping address to checkout form

Tags: checkout, shipping-address

I'm making a custom shipping module. When a user selects the shipping method, I want it to populate the shipping address fields with some custom address data.

I have overridden the select shipping method handler like so:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method': 
'Vendor_Module/js/action/select-shipping-method'
        }
    }
};
```

I want to programatically set the form field values on the checkout page. Something like:

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address'
], function (quote, shipping) {
    'use strict';

    return function (shippingMethod) {
        shipping.street("99 Road Street");
        shipping.city("New York");
    };
});
```

Is there a way to do this without just dumping in the values using jquery?

Comment: you want to customer address ??

Comment: Please refer this link may be help :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233245/how-to-set-a-custom-shipping-address-on-checkout-page?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but this describes it for the backend - I need it purely in frontend using JS

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters into object in this file
**"new-customer-address.js"** is setting up the shipping address. find file in Magento_Checkout/js/model/ code library.

just add the values into these parameters

`email: shipping_address.email,
            countryId: countryId,
            regionId: regionId || shipping_address.regionId,
            regionCode: shipping_address.region ? shipping_address.region['region_code'] : null,
            region: shipping_address.region ? shipping_address.region.region : null,
            customerId: shipping_address['customer_id'] || shipping_address.customerId,
            street: shipping_address.street ? _.compact(shipping_address.street) : shipping_address.street,
            company: shipping_address.company,
            telephone: shipping_address.telephone,
            fax: shipping_address.fax,
            postcode: shipping_address.postcode ? shipping_address.postcode : DefaultPostCodeResolver.resolve(),
            city: shipping_address.city,
            firstname: shipping_address.firstname,
            lastname: shipping_address.lastname,
            middlename: shipping_address.middlename,
            prefix: shipping_address.prefix,
            suffix: shipping_address.suffix,
            vatId: shipping_address['vat_id'],
            saveInAddressBook: shipping_address['save_in_address_book'],
            customAttributes: shipping_address['custom_attributes']`